# Access non ssh windows hosts and apply cmd commands remotely

Tags: windows, remote-access

We used to SSH into Windows machines remotely, execute commands, and get replies using the JSch API like:

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(""cmd /c  dir"+"\r\n"");

InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            String sScriptStatus=""; 
            byte[] tmp=new byte[20000];
            while(true){   ...


        }
```

But now we have to access a large group of machines which do not have SSH enabled, and we don't want to change anything on these machines. Is there another similar API built-into Windows that we could use?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment and requirements, you could use [wmic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) or [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) to execute remote commands.

psexec:

```
psexec \\remote-computer cmd /c dir
```

wmic:

```
wmic /node:remote-computer process call create "cmd /c dir"
```

Comment: hi Razvan , thanks for reply . i am using java multi-threading technology as i want to execute cmd command at thousand of hosts at the same time so i was hopping if i can run the command on the cmd of accessed host itself as i think it will cause many issues and speed down the process if i did it from my windows command line .

Comment: You could still put each psexec/wmic call in a separate thread. The only command that's being run on your application machine is the psexec/wmic call, not the remote command (ie. "cmd /c dir"). So, instead of an SSH client, you would have psexec/wmic.